# How to skip errors when using json_extract_path_text in Redshift?

Tags: sql, arrays, json, linux, amazon-redshift

I have the following query:

```
SELECT 'curl -s http://www.mde.operator.com/MRE/api?profile=CANCEL_AUTH&mode=assync-oneway&Auth='||json_extract_path_text(external_reference_id,'transactionIdAuth') + '&NUM=' + phone  FROM dbo.cancelled WHERE id like '%Auth%';
```

It will bring more than 60 thousands results, but the json is broken and I cannot manage to delete the broken lines.

Is there any way to skip the rows which shows any kind of errors?

Note: It isn't null rows.

I've already try:

```
json_extract_path_text(regexp_replace(event_properties,'\\\\.',''),'someValue')
```

Comment: Hi, anyone can give me a clue about this problem?

Answer (score 3):

You can make them null rows though, by setting the `null_if_invalid` argument of the `json_extract_path_text` function to `true`.

Source: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/JSON_EXTRACT_PATH_TEXT.html